# If statement and too much printing

Tags: java, if-statement

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong here. In the third scenario if (i == n && i % 2 == 0), I only want  it to print out 16 once (as given in the main method). But for some odd reason it prints it out 3 times. Can somebody explain why???

```
public class Foursix {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      printEven(1,7);
      printEven(21,2);
      printEven(16,16);
   //main
   }

   public static void printEven(int i, int n) {

      System.out.print("[ ");
      //n is greater than i
      if (i <= n) {
         for (int t = i; t <= n; t++) {
            if (t % 2 == 0) {
               System.out.print(t + " ");
            //if statement inner
            }
         //for loop
         }
      //if statement outer
      }

      //i is greater than n
      if (i >= n) {
         for (int t = i; t >= n; t--) {
            if (t % 2 == 0) {
               System.out.print(t + " ");
            //if statement inner
            }
         //for loop
         }
      //if statement outer
      }

      //i is the same as n
      if (i == n && i % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.print(i);
         //if statement
         }
      System.out.print("]");
      System.out.println();  
   //printEven
   }

//class
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're passing in 16,16, so all three of your `if()` conditions are TRUE:

```
  if (i <= n) {    16 <= 16 -> TRUE
  if (i >= n) {    16 >= 16 -> TRUE
  if (i == n && i % 2 == 0) {   16 == 16 && 16 % 2  -> TRUE
```

Given that you're explicitly testing for all three of greater than/less than/equal, you probably want these:

```
 if (i < n) { ... }
 else if (i > n) { ... }
 else if (i % 2 == 0) { ... }
```